# Faulty dataset on Worldclim.org

Tags: climate-models, open-data, gis, climate-data, r

I am currently working on a research project regarding climate sensitivities of plant species and I need to analyze future climate data. Worldclim.org has a broad spectrum of climate data based on current global climate models. I want to analyze the data using GIS applications such as ArcGIS Pro and QGIS as well as R.

However one particular dataset I need to analyze (MPI-ESM 1.2 HR with 30 seconds spatial resolutuion for SSP5-8.5) seems to be completely empty. All cells have "no data" assigned to them. The dataset is still 2GB large as it covers the whole earth. All the other datasets I looked at are somewhat larger (e.g. 8-10 GB) and work fine. Is there something obvious I am missing or is the data indeed faulty?

I tried contacting the people at worldclim.org regarding this issue a few weeks ago but I got no response as of today.

Worldclim.org:
https://worldclim.org/data/cmip6/cmip6climate.html

Download Link of the faulty dataset:
https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/cmip6/30s/MPI-ESM1-2-HR/ssp585/wc2.1_30s_bioc_MPI-ESM1-2-HR_ssp585_2061-2080.tif

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or knows an alternative source for the same data?

Comment: Could you resolve it? I have the same problem

Comment: Sadly I could not. I had to use the dataset with lower spatial resolution.